# VGG16 with other input shape and Imagenet weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, shapes

I'm new to models like VGG16. I've been searching information about this model and I still have doubts about it. I have 10000 images of different sizes to train the model (2 classes), so I decided to use an image size of 86x86 because of computational limitations and it's near average of every image size. So I did that:

```
base_model16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(86,86,3))
```

And for generators:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_vgg16) 

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(path_train,
                                                    target_size=(86,86),
                                                    color_mode='rgb',
                                                    batch_size = 128,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    shuffle=True)
```

I read that VGG16 was trained with 224x224 and I understood that we can use other size, but can someone confirm if i am doing it right? Because i am using imagenet weights and preprocess_vgg16 and it was with 224x224.
Sorry if anyone has already asked this question before but i need help understanding it please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to modify the Vgg model because it is designed to classify 1000 images. setting include_top=False removes the top layer of the model which had 1000 neurons. Now we need to include a layer which will have 2 neurons in it. The code below will accomplish that. Note in the parameters of the VGG model I have set pooling='max'. This results in the output of the Vgg model to be a vector that can be used as input to a dense layer.

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.VGG16( include_top=False, input_shape=(86,86,3), 
                                        pooling='max', weights='imagenet' ) 
x=base_model.output
output=Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy')
```

As an aside I do not like to use VGG16. It has about 40 million traninable parameters so it is computationally expense resulting in long training time. I prefer to use the MobileNet model which only has about 4 million trainable parameters and is about as accurate. To use the MobileNet model just use this line of code instead of the code for the Vgg model. Note I set the image_shape to (128,128,3) because there is a version of the mobilenet weights trained on imagenet with  128 X 128 images that will download automatically and help the model converge faster. But you can use 86 X86 if you choose. So in your train_generator set  target_size=(128,128). Also in the ImageDataGenerator the code preprocessing_function=preprocess_vgg16 should still work for the Mobilenet model because I think it is the same as keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input. I believe both of them just rescale the pixels to be between -1 and +1.

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False, 
           input_shape=(128,128,3), pooling='max', weights='imagenet',dropout=.4)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am going to try MobileNet too with 128x128. Do I have to resize previously all of my images to 128x128 instead of 86x86? I am using the code below:
img = img.resize((128,128))

Comment: You can use the same image size, but MobileNet will use the closest input size weights that it was originally trained on, which is 128x128. Mobilenet has pretrained weights for (128, 128), (160, 160), (192, 192), or (224, 224), so 128 is the closest to your size

Comment: Ok thank you! One more question: I have 3 generators, should I use in ImageDataGenerator preprocessing_function=preprocess_vgg16 in test generator like I use for training and validation generators when I use flow_from_directory? (My dataset is split in train / validation / test)

Comment: You should always process your test images in the same way you process the training set except do not include image augmentation and set shuffle=False